# SSMS Custom Keyboard Query Shortcut With(NoLock)

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a custom Keyboard Query Shortcut in SSMS (2008) with the following t-sql...

```
SELECT TOP(50) * FROM
```

This allows me to simply type in a name of a table and press my keyboard shortcut to get the top fifty items from that table.  The problem I have is that I like to query using WITH(NOLOCK) so the records don't get locked.  I haven't figured out how to enter T-SQL into the Keyboard Query shortcut where the input is in the middle of the statement.  How can I incorporate a NoLock without resorting to using a stored procedure?

Comment: You could append `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED ` to the front of your query. This would obviously switch the option on for your connection until you turn it off again though (maybe another short cut key to do that!).

Comment: Thanks for that helpful advice.  A major goal of this question is to identify a way where the input of the Query Shortcut can be in the middle of the T-Sql.. SELECT TOP(1) * From (Input Here) WHERE ID=123, so I could type in a table name, press the shortcut, and the record is brought up with the ID of 123 (assuming ID is a valid field name).

Comment: Never really used shortcut keys. You can do this with templates though `SELECT TOP(50) * FROM [<table_name, sysname, YourTable>]  WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE [<col_name, sysname, YourColumn>] =  <col_value, any, SomeValue>` Then `CTRL+SHIFT+M` to fill in the blanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can get a bit messy, but you can use `sp_executesql` to avoid relying on a stored procedure being defined:

```
sp_executesql N'EXEC(''SELECT TOP(50) * FROM '' + @input + '' WITH(NOLOCK)'')', N'@input varchar(max)',
```

Comment: I love it, exactly what I needed!
Take note: if you need to run this query in a different db than connected to, quotes ared needed -> 'otherdb..mytable'. Otherwise mytable without quotes suffices.

Answer (score 2):

I have developed **SSMSBoost** ssms **add-in** - it has autoreplacements feature.
You can define there:

Replacement token: "selt50"

Replacement string:"SELECT TOP(50) * FROM # WITH(NOLOCK)"

`#` tells there cursor will be placed, after replacement is done

so, when you then type

selt50 and_press_SPACE

selt50 will be replaced by

`SELECT TOP(50) * FROM # WITH(NOLOCK)`

with cursor blinking instead of #

ssmsboost comes with standart autoreplacements:

sel ->`select * from`

upd ->`update # set where`

deci-> `declare @# int`

you can certaily re-define them
it is generally well-done add-in with several very useful tools for ssms (preferred connections, code navigation etc)

Comment: I'm a big supporter of SSMSBoost, you guys do a great job! It keeps getting better and better. Best SSMS tools addin out there!

Answer (score 0):

Create a stored procedure sp_Top50 in master and assign the shortcut to that SP.
The sp_ prefix makes SQL Server to look for the stored procedure in master.

```
create procedure sp_Top50
  @T sysname
as
declare @S nvarchar(200)
set @S = 'select top(50) * from '+quotename(@T)+ ' with(nolock)'
exec (@S)
```